# How do I set the Publisher in Windows install

Tags: visual-studio-2017, setup-project, publisher, control-panel

I have created a Setup Wizard installer in Visual Studio 2017.  My application is installed but the Control Panel|Programs and Features does not show the correct Name or the Publisher.  The name shows up as "Setup" and the Publisher is "Default Company Name".

I have added the company certificate to the executable project and have defined the "Publisher Name" and "Product Name" on the "Publish Options" dialog.

How do I define these items, either in the application project or the setup project,  so they show up in the "Programs and Features" correctly?

Comment: Right clicking on the setup project and selecting the Properties from the popup menu brings up a Build properties dialog that does not have the information.Click on the setup project in the Solution Explorer and then open the Properties Pane.  Edit the Manufacturer and the ProductName properties.

Answer (score 0):

Right clicking on the setup project and selecting the Properties from the popup menu brings up a Build properties dialog that does not have the information.

Click on the setup project in the Solution Explorer and then open the Properties Pane.  Edit the Manufacturer and the ProductName properties.